# onnouseover not working in chrome, was working until update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onmouseover

I have the following function being called via onmouseover on an

```
    function showTooltip(tip, el, evt) {
    if (document.layers) {
        if (!el.tip) {
            el.tip = new Layer(200);
            el.tip.document.open();
            el.tip.document.write(tip);
            el.tip.document.close();
            el.onclick = function (evt) { this.tip.visibility = 'hide'; };
            el.onmouseout = function (evt) { this.tip.visibility = 'hide'; };
        }
        el.tip.left = evt.pageX;
        el.tip.top = evt.pageY;
        el.tip.visibility = 'show';
    }
    else if (document.all) {
        if (!el.tip) {
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<DIV ID="tip' + tc + '" CLASS="tooltip">' + tip + '<\/DIV>');
            el.tip = document.all['tip' + tc++];
            el.onclick = function (evt) { this.tip.style.visibility = 'hidden'; };
            el.onmouseout = function (evt) { this.tip.style.visibility = 'hidden'; };
        }
        el.tip.style.pixelLeft = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - 200
        el.tip.style.pixelTop = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + 10
        el.tip.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

the call looks like;

```
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DocumentList1_dg_imgNotes_0" onmouseover="javascript:showTooltip('<b>Pages:</b> 1<br><b>Date:</b> 8/7/2014<br><b>Rep ID:</b> 789',this,event);" src="/applications/Images/icons/no-a.bmp" align="absmiddle" style="border-width:0px;">
```

with the event of;

```
onmouseover="javascript:showTooltip('<b>Pages:</b> 1<br><b>Date:</b> 8/7/2014<br><b>Rep ID:</b> 789',this,event);"
```

this code has been working without a hitch for upwards of a year and still functions correctly in Firefox and IE, but not is Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m.  I am no expert, but I feel like the declarations are all fine and the information being passed it alright, but when it hits the function it just steps over the if(document.layers) and the else if(document.all) when debugging, however, when in IE and debugging it steps into the else if statement just find and renders the tooltip for the exact same site.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`document.all` and `document.layers` is obsolete.  They are no longer supported by chrome.

Comment: alright, guess i'll start the digging and re-building of that stuff too, deprecated a lot in these new releases huh?